# Referencing cells from a Contract Sheet to a Order Sheet

Tags: excel

There are two separate MS Excel workbooks, the first one is named `Contract` and has column `Code`. Each `Code` has two prices, the first one has length 3 or less and the second one has length 4 or more.

There is also column `Code` in the second workbook named `Order`. I want to have the auto filler for the price in the next cell.

There are around 800 unique values in the column `Code` and all of them have the given price structure. I have tried a `SUMPRODUCT` formula and it has worked great but you aren't able to reference more than 12 cells (there is displayed en error if you try to do it).

```
=VLOOKUP($D2, Sheet2!$A$2:$B$65535, 2, FALSE)
```

I have seen this formula somwhere on this site but what can I do to work it with my data?

Comment: You just need to pull in the two prices for the code that was entered? Do you need to sum the two prices, or just list them on the same row?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try in E2:

```
=VLOOKUP($D2,[Contract.xlsx]Sheet2!$A:$C,2,0)
```

in F2:

```
=VLOOKUP($D2,[Contract.xlsx]Sheet2!$A:$C,3,0)
```

and copy both down to suit. Assumes Workbook Contract has Sheet2 with `code` in ColumnA and the two sets of prices in ColumnsB:C to match by row.